# Django: migrate subapp model.py file

Tags: python, django, django-models

My issue is the following. How to migrate a the models in models.py file that is not the automatically generated with `django-admin startapp appname`

I have made a simple directory that illustrates my issue:

```
example_app
├── app.py
├── models.py
├── tenants
│   └── tenant1
│       ├── models.py
│       └── tenant1_views.py
├── tests.py
└── views.py
```

so what I want is to migrate what is inside of tenant1.models.py

I have not found any clue on how to achieve this, does anyone know?

Comment: Add the subapp to `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: even if it is not a django generated app? and what would the command look like to makemigration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django will look into models for all apps defined in `INSTALLED_APPS`, an app may not be created by `django-admin startapp` or `manage.py startapp` but may be added to `INSTALLED_APPS`. Django will look for a subclass of `AppConfig` in your app and if it doesn't find one it will use base `AppConfig`, hence you may want to add a `apps.py` file to your subapp and add an `AppConfig` to configure it properly:

In `tenant1` add an `apps.py`:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class Tenant1Config(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.AutoField'
    name = 'tenants.tenant1'
```

Next add your subapp to `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'tenants.tenant1',
    ...
]
```

Next you should add a `migrations` directory with an `__init__.py` file to your app so that it may be detected directly by the migrations system. After this simply run:

```
python manage.py makemigrations

# Alternatively, the below command will automatically make a migrations directory
python manage.py makemigrations tenant1
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine, this does exactly what I needed it to do! thanks Abdul Aziz